# getUserMedia - what if user makes no choice?

Tags: javascript, promise, microphone, getusermedia

I've adapted a library to record MP3 audio via the user's microphone. If the user allows or rejects the microphone access request, I'm fine, but I note that [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) this:

> Note that it is possible for the returned promise to neither resolve
>   nor reject, as the user is not required to make a choice.

But it doesn't seem to say what, if anything, I can do catch that "no choice made" action. If the user merely quits the dialog, or blurs out of it without making a choice, can I catch that and adjust my UI accordingly?

Here's my current code:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then(function(stream) {
    build_ui();
    startUserMedia(stream);
}).catch(function(e) { //<-- doesn't fire if no choice made
    cfg.no_device_callback && cfg.no_device_callback(e);
});
```

Comment: I think you can use a `reject` method of the promise to catch that if the error is not thrown.

Comment: But that's just it - the promise is *not* rejected if the user makes no choice.

Comment: I can't imagine the case on the user has make no choice on 5 minutes, so you can start a timeout to reject manually if the user makes no choice on X minutes.

Comment: That's true. Weird how there's no notif, though. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the tiny help. I wish to be more useful. Good luck!

Comment: "No choice made" is an inaction, not an action. There's nothing to catch. If this is about Firefox's permission prompt then see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34834296/918910). Note also that [Firefox Dev Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) introduces a more modal prompt, which should help with your concern with forcing the user to make a choice.

Comment: @jib - semantically you're correct, but from a developer's point of view you'd still want to know if that "inaction" occurs. Thanks for the info re: Firefox Dev.

Comment: @Utkanos Inaction by definition does not occur.

Comment: OK now you're just being pedantic. You know well what I mean. It's something that would be good to catch. There's really nothing more to discuss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a timeout on the promise you have.

For instance, you could extend the Promise object and prototype as follows:

```
Promise.wait = function (ms) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
};

Promise.prototype.timeout = function(ms) {
    return Promise.race([
        this, 
        Promise.wait(ms).then(function () {
            throw new Error("time out");
        })
    ])
};
```

Once you have that, you can just chain in a `.timeout(10000)`:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
         .timeout(10000).then(function(stream) {
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    build_ui();
    startUserMedia(stream);
}).catch(function(e) { //<-- now also fires if no choice made within 10 secs
    cfg.no_device_callback && cfg.no_device_callback(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox (57) **does not allow** the user to dismiss the permissions dialog. This dialog will remain visible indefinitely until you make a choice:

[image]

Safari (11) **does not allow** the user to dismiss the dialog. On top of that it also locks the entire browser (including other tabs) and thus forces the user's hand to make a choice:

[image]

Chrome (62) **allows** the user to dismiss the dialog through the top right [x] button:

[image]

In this case the choice and actionis obvious so Chrome throws a non spec error named `PermissionDismissedError` but this error might be removed in Chrome 64 which attempts to move towards spec compliant errors (see [this Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721412)).

I've written more abut `getUserMedia` errors in [this article](https://blog.addpipe.com/common-getusermedia-errors/).

Comment: Firefox mobile allows the user to click on the page to make the prompt disappear. The Facebook embedded browser doesn't display the prompt and the promise does not return.